# Convergence of the inverse partial sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Given a sequence $(x_n)$ we define by induction the sequence of sequences
$$\begin{cases}S_0(n)&=x_n\newline S_{m+1}(n)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{S_{m}(k)}\end{cases}$$

Let’s take the example of $(x_n)=\log(n+2)$, we would have
$$S_1(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{\log(k+2)}$$ which diverges
$$S_2(n)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\log(2)}}+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\log(2)}+\frac{1}{\log(3)}}+…+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\log(2)}+\frac{1}{\log(3)}+…+\frac{1}{\log(n+2)}}$$ which might diverge aswell according to python.

My question is, given any sequence $(x_n)$, is there a rank m for which (S_m(n)) converges ? And can we bound it by any constant ?

I’ve never seen such an exercice and struggle to make use of the equivalents here…

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, it is fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

This will highly depend on what initial sequence $x_n$ we chose. Your example however ($x_n=\log(n+2)$) doesn't converge on any rank $m$. [image] Furthermore even if for a sequence $x_n$ it did converge at say rank $m_0$, we cannot conclude from there that it will converge for ranks $m>m_0$.

An example of converging rank is rank $1$ of series $x_n=n^2+1$, where $S_1(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2+1} \le 1 + \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

EDIT : I just realized I missed your actual question entirely. For any sequence ${x_n}$, either $S_0$ or $S_1$ converges. The rest of the sequences always diverge, but there do exist the limit of these sequences at $\sqrt{2 x}$